# How to avoid an extra border-top thickness on bootstrap input field in iphone?

Tags: html, css

I used the bootstrap input field on a form, but an unnecessary thickness on the border-top line is found on the iphone. The css code is given below:

```
.form-group .form-control {
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[image: screenshot of issue]

Is there any way to remove this border-top thickness in iphone ?
All the feedback for this are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to remove the unwanted shadow within the text input field on iOS.

```
 background-clip: padding-box;
```

Hope this helps. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.form-group .form-control {
   outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```